# Regex- replace match with middle between delimiters

Tags: c#, regex

I have some html that I am trying to parse out which has some merge variables.  The variables are delimited, starting with `%x.` and ending with `%`.  For example:   `%x.VALUE%`  What I'm trying to do is replace the entire match with just the "VALUE".

So, `%x.VALUE%`  becomes just `VALUE`.

I tried using MSDN's substitution examples using

```
string input = "aaaaa%nomatch%bbb%x.FOO%ccc%x.BAR%ddddd%%";
string pattern = @"%x.(.*?)%";
string substitute = "$&";

string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, substitute);
```

and I tried it with a couple of different substitution strings but none worked.  I realize the `$&` just replaces it with itself so it doesn't really do anything but I don't know how to replace the entire match with just the middle.  Does it use some sort of nested regex?

**Edit:**
For that string, I would expect the result to be

```
aaaaa%nomatch%bbbFOOcccBARddddd%%
```

Here the `%x.FOO%` is replaced with `FOO` and `%x.BAR%` replaced with `BAR` but the other `%` don't have the `x.` so they are not matches and are unchanged.

Comment: Can you give an expected output for that input?

Comment: Use `$1` for that. And escape the dot.

Comment: Try this @"%x[^%]+";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that `$&` is a backreference to the whole match. The `$1` backreference will replace with the value *captured* into the first capturing group.

Use

```
%x\.(.*?)%
```

or

```
%x\.([^%]*)%
```

And replace with `$1` backreference.

C#:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(input, @"%x\.([^%]*)%", "$1");
```

See more about [*Substitutions in Regular Expressions*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0(v=vs.110).aspx) at MSDN.

To return `FOO` or `BAR`, i.e. to return the contents of the  first capturing group, use

```
var results = Regex.Matches(input, @"%x\.([^%]*)%")
      .Cast<Match>()
      .Select(p => p.Groups[1].Value)
      .ToList();
```

See [the regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%25x%5c.(.*%3f)%25&i=aaaaa%25nomatch%25bbb%25x.FOO%25ccc%25x.BAR%25ddddd%25%25&r=%241).

Answer (score 2):

You will need to escape that `.` with `\.`. Otherwise, it will match anything. And `$1` is for referencing the first group, `(.+?)`.

```
// returns: aaaaa%nomatch%bbbFOOcccBARddddd%%
Regex.Replace(
    "aaaaa%nomatch%bbb%x.FOO%ccc%x.BAR%ddddd%%",
    @"%x\.(.+?)%",
    "$1")
```

Comment: This is awesome, thanks.  As a side question, if I want to return just the matches `FOO` and `BAR` (not doing the replacement) how do I do that?  I keep getting the full `%x.FOO%` returned.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew!

Comment: This answer needs to be all over the internet. THANK YOU!